# Constant time std::list resize to a given last element?

Tags: c++, list

Resizing a `std::list` is linear time since it needs to find the `n`th element first.

But is it possible to point to an element (using iterator) and resize in constant time by declaring that the pointed-to element is the new last element?

It would be something like:
`make_last(const_iterator pos)`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, in C++11 general `std::list` splicing is O(n), in order to get O(1) size checking.

Otherwise you could have moved the undesired items to another list.

But even that's just a half solution, since the items have to be destroyed at some point. However, if constant time splicing was guaranteed this would make a *temporary* resize O(1).

---

A practical solution is to use e.g. `std::vector` instead of `std::list`.

Due to necessity of destroying it doesn't give you O(1) resizing either, except when the resizing discards a constant number of items at the end, but it avoids all that complexity.

With the decision to make `std::list::size` a constant time operation, I do not know of any remaining reason to use `std::list` for anything.

Comment: "With the decision to make std::list::size a constant time operation, I do not know of any remaining reason to use std::list for anything." - I agree the `size()` decision's frustrating and dubious, but that's exasperation talking - still several clear advantages over other containers that I'm sure I don't need to list....

Answer (score 0):

In C++03 you use [erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) on the first element you don't want - constant time iff the optimiser realises the elements don't need destruction.

In C++11 you're stuffed... it's obliged to work out the new size as Alf explains.